# Code implemented according statemachine pattern does not work

Tags: java, state-machine

I am trying to solve statediagram exercise, but still have not understood why my code does not work.

I chave already cheked all possible code examles of code, but have not understood why mine version does not pass any tests.May be I chve some sort of small mistake which not easy to see. Below I provide my code, test semples and digramms I have.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SQAiwUBo1OwI-QKksxciDS7dEdKGS6dn [1]
   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JhdScK7t1XmNc3eLT7hSGpwyYDLWl46T [2]

```
public class GarageDoor {
    private Motor motor;
    private DoorState currentState;
    public GarageDoor() {
        this.setState(new Closed(this));
        //currentState=new Closed(this);
    }

    public void openDoor(){
        currentState.openDoor();

    }

    public void stopper(){
        currentState.stopper();

    }

    public void closeDoor(){
        currentState.closeDoor();

    }

    public Motor getMotor(){
        return this.motor;
    }

    private void setState(DoorState ds){
        this.currentState=ds;

    }


    public abstract class DoorState{
        public abstract void openDoor();
        public abstract void closeDoor();
        public abstract void stopper();

    }

    public class Closed extends DoorState{
        private GarageDoor garageDoor;
        public Closed(GarageDoor garageDoor){
            this.garageDoor=garageDoor;
        }

        @Override
        public void openDoor() {

            garageDoor.setState(new Opening(garageDoor));
            garageDoor.getMotor().upwards();

        }

        @Override
        public void closeDoor() {
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        }

        @Override
        public void stopper() {
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        }
    }

    }
```

Actually I cann not execute main()

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        //Motor motor=new Motor();

        GarageDoor gd=new GarageDoor();
        gd.openDoor();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you're setting `motor` anywhere, so in `Closed.openDoor`, when you call `garageDoor.getMotor().upwards()` you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Also, I see that you're passing `GarageDoor` in to the `Closed` state and then calling `garageDoor.setState`. Consider just returning the next state from each `DoorState` method.

Comment: public class Motor {
    public void upwards(){
        System.out.println("Motor goes left");

    }

    public void downwards(){
        System.out.println("Motor goes right");

    }

    public void stop(){
        System.out.println("Motor is stoppped");

    }

Comment: I have Motor class already, but it should not influence my code so much I could not execute openDoor() method...or?
I do not understand your sentence
"Also, I see that you're passing GarageDoor in to the Closed state and then calling garageDoor.setState. Consider just returning the next state from each DoorState method."

Answer (score 0):

1) Try having GarageDoor extend DoorState, seems to override the same methods.

2) Nowhere in your code do you actually create the Motor in the `GarageDoor` class.

You need to initiate the Motor, e.g:

```java
public GarageDoor() {
    this.motor = new Motor();
}
```

Comment: Acctually I am not allowed to use Enums according my class diagramm task...

Comment: Mhmm that's annoying. Have you tried setting GarageDoor to extend DoorState rather than have a DoorState? Appears to override the methods anyway

Comment: Here is all my code
https://drive.google.com/open?id=12pOnn-gc3s2MN6Qvm9AgkNQWEOAv0FXz
https://drive.google.com/open?id=10GkpdoUM7neH90kAoWqeYYFc27aYB9u3

Comment: @Fedo don't worry, I am quite advanced with Java and make the same mistakes all the time, spend hours wondering why, and 90% of the time it's something simple like this :P